# grep: count all matches to all patterns

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I have tens of thousands of (fixed) patterns that I want to find matches for in a very large file.  I would like to count the total number of hits for each pattern.  I can't find anything in the grep documentation that suggests this is possible.  My setup would look something like this:

`gunzip -c bigfile.txt.gz | grep -c -f patterns.txt`

Of course this counts lines that matched *anything* in `patterns.txt`, when what I want are the individual counts of hits for each pattern.  Is something like this possible on the command line with grep?  Or will I have to write a program?

Comment: Are  you sure `grep -f patterns.txt` can load thousands of patterns? My experience was after 2048 lines of text in patterns.txt, I had to find src code for grep and modify to increase search list size. (This was under solaris, in mid 2000s, but I think I had similar problems with the gnu utils at that time). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about doing it for all patterns at once, but you could write a bash script that reads them one at a time and do grep  | wc -l for each one.

Comment: will take N times as long, where N has been specified by OP as thousands. Good luck to all.

Comment: Yes it will. It's a possible option, I unfortunately couldn't think of a better one.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like so:

```
gunzip -c bigfile.txt.gz | grep -f patterns.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

The sort may be kind of large as it'll save the entire output. A quick perl/python/... script with a hash could cut that down substantially though.

```
$ grep -f pats.txt a.txt  | ./t.rb 
a 3
b 3
c 2
```

Here's the script that avoids the sort, see if it actually speeds things up.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
results = {}
while gets
  line = $_.chomp
  results[line] ||= 0
  results[line]+= 1
end
results.each { |k,v| puts ""#{k} #{v}"}
```

Comment: When I do `grep -f patterns.txt a.txt  | ./t.rb` I get
`./t.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'`.  I don't know anything about ruby, so I can't debug that.  I'm gradually starting to think that the larger issue is that grep isn't suited to what I wanted to do; it's designed for finding one or a handful of patterns, not the tens of thousands I'm interested in.  Time to dust off my C skills and write a little program, I guess.  Thanks anyway for the suggestions.